# Retrieve Jira LinkTypes via JIRA REST API

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jira-rest-java-api

I need to get a complete list of all `LinkTypes` known by Jira. Since I couldn't find any documentation which provides this info, I would prefer to retrieve all types via the JIRA REST API. Is there a way to do that?

```
 List<Type> types = jiraRestClient.runQuery("https://jira-host.com/rest/api/latest/<allLinkTypes>");

    ... 

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "id", "name", "inward", "outward", "self" })
public class Type
{

    @JsonProperty("id")
    private String              id;
    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String              name;
    @JsonProperty("inward")
    private String              inward;
    @JsonProperty("outward")
    private String              outward;
    @JsonProperty("self")
    private String              self;
```

The rest client is already up and running. I just need the URL for the retrieval.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure but I think you are looking for this REST request.

> /rest/api/2/issueLinkType

Example :
https://jira.atlassian.com/rest/api/2/issueLinkType

Also you can find documentation here.

https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/

Thanks.